# Taking a publishing site offline

Tags: publishing-site, offline

I understand that I can bring html files down for offline viewing. What I would like though is to bring down an entire site and have the user experience similar to when the user is connected. Is this possible? Are there any third party products that would fulfill this requirement?

Edit - What I am asking is how I can take a SharePoint publishing site offline. Or is that not even possible? I really do not want to use OneDrive to bring down a bunch of HTML pages in a library.

Thanks,

Les

Comment: Not possible. I would probably ask you to look at other options. Can you let us know why you would keep an offline copy and are after the offline experience? What is the actual problem we are trying to solve? We can look at other options.

Comment: Thanks Arvi. The use case for this is we have many field engineers working in remote areas with no connectivity (or in customers locations where they are not granted access to the wifi). These inspectors need access to electronic manuals that are currently HTML based. At this point I am leaning towards a non-SharePoint solution or storing a PDF version of the manual in Sharepoint and pushing them down to clients via 3rd party product (or OneDrive) to keep them synchronized. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention why you wanted an offline version, so depending on that this may be too meaty of a solution for your needs. Unfortunately there isn't a quick solution for what you are asking for.

You could run a SharePoint virtual machine on your computer and then back up and restore your site to the VM. This will give you offline capability and a replica of the site, at least from the time that you did the backup.

I am not sure if you are 2010, 2013, 2016, Online but what version you are running will dictate how much work you will have to do to get a VM up and running. And I don't believe you can create a VM for SharePoint Online. With that you would have to save down the pages manually. For 2013 and 2016 there are VMs already created that you can download and use. You can probably find an old 2010 version around somewhere. The Microsoft hosted one is no longer available.

You also need to have admin rights on your existing site in order to do a backup of the SharePoint site.

There are a ton of VM resources, especially for more recent versions, that you can reference. Here are a few to get you started.

https://gauravmahajan.net/2017/10/06/sharepoint-server-2016-virtual-machine-download/

https://github.com/CriticalPathTraining/SharePoint2016VmSetupGuide

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/set-up-a-general-development-environment-for-sharepoint

Comment: Thanks for your comments. the use case is to bring electronic manuals offline. The clients in this case are primarily Surface Pros and iPads. While we're not on Office 365 yet, that is where we are headed. I think the reality is we will need a different solution.